# I need help with this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Someone can help me with this integral please?

$$
\int ne^{-n^2} dn
$$

I tried with parts

$$
u = e^{-n^2}    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v = n \ dn
$$

$$
du = -e^{-n^2}2n    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  v = \int n  \ dn,  \ \ \ v = \frac{n^2}{2}
$$

Then,

$$
\int ne^{-n^2} dn = \frac{e^{-n^2}n^2}{2} + \int n^3e^{-n^2} dn
$$

After, I tried with parts again, but I can't get to answer

Comment: What is the derivative of $n \mapsto e^{-n^2}$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Let $u=n^{2}$.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: That should give the answer since then $du=2ndn$ so $\int ne^{-n^{2}}dn=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-n^{2}}2ndn=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-t}dt$. This last integral can be solved.

Comment: You right, Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Do $u = -n^2$, and you get $du = -2n\,dn$, and so

$$ \int\,ne^{-n^2}dn = -\dfrac{1}{2}\int\,e^u\,du$$